# how to use async/await method instead of this method

Tags: reactjs

```
const handleClick = (dispatch) => {
    if (state.trackTitle) {
      axios
        .get(`${apiURL}/suggest/${state.trackTitle}`)
        .then((res) => {
          dispatch({
            type: "SEARCH_TRACKS",
            payload: res.data.data,
            next: res.data.next,
            prev: res.data.prev,
          });
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    } else {
      alert("Please insert song !!");
    }
  };
```

Comment: You need a basic tutorial for this. See e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const handleClick = async (dispatch) => {
    if (state.trackTitle) {
try{
        const response = await 
         axios.get(`${apiURL}/suggest/${state.trackTitle}`)
        await dispatch({
            type: "SEARCH_TRACKS",
            payload: response.data.data,
            next: response.data.next,
            prev: response.data.prev,
          });
        }
        catch(error){console.log(error)};
    } else {
      alert("Please insert song !!");
    }
  };
```